# How to create a Spektral graph with edge weights and edge features

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I want to create a Graph in Spektral which has both edged weights and edge labels. I have three matrices: a nxn adjacency matrix, an nx4 feature matrix for the nodes, and an nxnx2 matrix which represents the label for each edge. I do not know how to incorporate this third matrix into my Graph so that the edges will be labeled. I would also be happy to label the edges manually, but I don't know how to do that either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `spektral.data.Graph` data structure has an attribute called `e` to store edge attributes.
So, if you have your data stored into numpy arrays you can do:

```
g = Graph(x=x, a=a, e=e)
```

where `e` is your edge attributes matrix.

They will be picked up automatically by the data loaders, if you use them.

Check out the documentation [here](https://graphneural.network/data/#graph).